Kendo PDF Angular does not read special characters
I am using Kendo to create a PDF, but I need to display special characters like 'Frío.' However, it doesn’t print correctly; it only shows 'FR˝O.'. How can I fix it?. I am using several fonts and many configurations.
Part of my code:
<kendo-pdf-export #pdf2 paperSize="letter" margin="0.4cm" landscape="true" forcePageBreak=".page-break" style="@font-face {
        font-family: 'DejaVuSans', Arial, sans-serif;
        src: url('https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans.ttf') format('truetype');
    };
    font-family: 'DejaVuSans', Arial, sans-serif;">
      <ng-template kendoPDFTemplate let-pageNum="pageNum" let-totalPages="totalPages">
<div class="col-lg">
                <strong class="text-left text d-block mb-1" *ngIf="ClienteMolino && ClienteMolino != null">Cliente: {{ClienteMolino}}</strong>
                <!-- <strong style="font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;" class="text-left text d-block mb-1">Producto: {{Producto}}</strong> -->
                <strong style="font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;" class="text-left text d-block mb-1">
                    Producto: <span [innerHTML]="Producto"></span>
                </strong>
                <!-- <strong class="text-left text d-block mb-1" *ngIf="Spec && Spec != null">Especificacion y tipo: {{Spec}}</strong> -->
              </div>
</ng-template>
</kendo-pdf-export>


The issue with special characters like Frío not displaying correctly in your Kendo PDF export likely stems from font embedding or encoding limitations. Ensuring the fonts support special characters and are properly embedded is essential but can be tedious to configure.
For a quick and hassle-free solution, consider using a third-party HTML to PDF conversion API like PageSnap.co. It uses advanced rendering engines, supports a wide range of fonts and character sets by default, and minimizes setup, ensuring accurate PDF outputs with minimal effort.
